# converting date in to same format as it was before in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, time, strtotime

I have to convert date format in to 'yyyy-mm-dd' become 'Y-M-d'

this is code:

```
$date =  '2014-12-17';
$fleet = date('ymd', strtotime($date));
```

but output:

```
700101
```

can you help me how to solved this problem?

thank you

Comment: Your problem more than likely cones from the $shift and $edca_id variables. How are they defined?

Comment: you should pass the `$date` variable not the array element `$date['date']`

Comment: i already edit like above but it same output

Comment: @news the first argument to `date()` should be `Y-m-d`

Comment: i already changed like this date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)); but out put 1970-01-01

Comment: @news but the date is already in desired format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood, but.

If you have a string date, as in your example, you could transform it in a Date Object, than you can format as you want.

See an example:

```
$date =  '2014-12-17';
$dateObj = date_create($date);

echo date_format($dateObj, 'Y-m-d'); // will show 2014-12-17
echo date_format($dateObj, 'd-m-Y'); // will show 17-12-2014
```

See if this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. You may need to set a default timezone depending on your system settings. Not really sure why you would have that output but it may be related.

```
$date = "2014-12-17";
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)); // same output 2014-12-17
echo date("y-m-d", strtotime($date)); // same output 14-12-17
```